# Displaying rows according to Specific Values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select several rows according to the attributes in Type column.

Let's pretend I have this dataframe:

```
Type | Killed | Survive
Dog      1         0
Cat      3         5
Dog      4         1
Cow      2         4
Fish     1         3
```

I would like to select the row that has Type = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish']

This would be my desire result:

```
Type  | Killed | Survived
Dog       1         0
Dog       4         1
Cat       3         5
Fish      1         3
```

I know that you can use :

```
 df[df['Type'] == 'Dog']
```

to get dog only.

but I would like to know how to select more than one type.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
df[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish']
```

Thanks for helping me guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df['Type'].isin(['Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish'])]
```